# good design to monitor a subprocess if they are alive or stuck. is observer pattern going to work here? and how?

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, data-structures

In my window-based java application, i am creating a subprocess to copy files from one location to another using robocopy.
The thread creating the subprocess waits for the subprocess until it is terminated.
There are seldom chances wherein this subprocess stucks.
For this, I want to write a monitor which will watch this subprocess until it is terminated properly or inform whether it is stuck.
Is there a better design which can help us achieve this.
Robocopy while copying generates the log file which can be used to see if the subprocess is actually running.
I am confused with how to approach this problem.
Currently what i have in mind is to have this subprocess act as a data generator in this case log file, and the monitor which will keep track of this log file and let the observer, basically the thread who creates the subprocess knows of the current status of the process, so that the parent thread can kill that Process or wait for its completion.
Is this design fine or can we approach it in a better way

Comment: Easiest solution is to let your program run through [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) in Windows. You need architectural solution to this problem instead of design, because later involves much work comparatively. Task scheduler allows to you to monitor the program with various options.

Comment: The subprocess needs to be monitored because if for some reason the subprocess stucks then the thread who is creating the subprocess should take actions like killing the process itself. Calling the Task scheduler from the java application and then monitoring it would make it more operating system specific. I want to avoid calling the task scheduler and instead want to write a monitor which will do. That's why needed more clarification on the design part.

Comment: Since your application is in Java, why not use Java to [copy the files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)?  A code loop is much easier to monitor than an external command whose output format is not guaranteed to be stable.  And as a bonus, using Java to copy the files is cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

If some thread is hanged or falls in undless loop it's a bug. 
Monitoring thread is a bad idea because in Java ideology, you can't control when threads terminate. (Ok, you could do that but in fact you have better ways).

Consider `FutureTask.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` Pseudocode:

```
FutureTask task = new FutureTask(new CopyRunnable(whatever), null);
someExecutor.execute(task);
try {
  task.get(12, TimeUnit.HOURS);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
 // the copying failed
}
```

With `new FutureTask(Callable)` you could get result, for example how many files were copied.